# jQuery/PHP Hide Div, Update Information from MySQL, Show Div New Information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, refresh

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".reload").click(function() {
        $("div#update").fadeOut("fast")
        .load("home.php div#update").fadeIn("fast")
    });
});
```

### PHP:

```
function statusUpdate() {

    $service_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service ORDER BY status");
    $service_num = mysql_num_rows($service_query);

    for ($x=1;$x<=$service_num;$x++) {
    $service_row = mysql_fetch_row($service_query);

    $second_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service WHERE sid='$service_row[0]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($second_query);

    $socket = @fsockopen($row[3], $row[4], $errnum, $errstr, 0.01); 
    if ($errnum >= 1) { $status = 'offline'; } else { $status = 'online'; }

    mysql_query("UPDATE service SET status='$status' WHERE sid='$row[0]'")
    or die(mysql_error());

    ?>

    <ul><li style="min-width:190px;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></li>
    <li style="min-width: 190px;" title="DNS: <?php echo $row[2]; ?>">
    <?php echo $row[3] . ':' . $row[4]; ?></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $status; ?>" style="min-width:80px;"><div id="update">
    <?php echo $status; ?></div></li></ul> 

    <?php

    } 
}

?>

<?php statusUpdate(); ?>
```

I have a button which I press (refresh) and that will then refresh the #update id to hopefully fadeOut all the results, and then fade in the new results... issue is it fades them out okay, but when it brings them back, it's just div on div and div and looks really messy - does not do what it's meant to do (would have to upload a picture to give further information).

In the short, what I want to happen is when you hit the update, they will all fade and then fade in with updated values from the php...  I made the php/mysql into a function so then I could call it when i hit that refresh button, thinking that would work, but I don't know how to do that...

Thank-you in advance,

Phillip.

Comment: first check in you firebug what response do you get

Comment: wouldn't know what to start looking at with that addon... haha.

Comment: go to firefox addon search firebug and install it, and expand it on by clicking on the right corner of your browser and active console and you will see the ajax reqest there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".reload").click(function() {
            $("div#update").fadeOut("fast");
            $.ajax({
                 url:'home.php',
                 data:{type:'getStatus'},
                 type;'post', 
                 success:function(data){
                    $('div#update').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
                 }
            });       
        });
    });
```

**php page format**

```
<?php
$type= $_POST['type'];
if($type=="getStatus")
{
    //get statuses from data base and return only formatted statuses in html
}
else
{
   //your page codes here
   //like tags <html>,<body> etc, all regular tags
   //<script> tags etc
}
?>
```

Comment: i noticed here you have function(data), yet the php function is statusUpdate ... how do i link that ajax command to the output/results of the statusUpdate function within home.php?

Comment: please tell me this so that i can update my code, the php page that is holding javascript and the one which is returning status are same ie. home.php??

Comment: home.php is holding all the information (html, php and jQuery).  jquery is running at the top under ready(function)

Comment: You have been an amazing help.  Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
.load("home.php div#update").fadeIn("fast")
```

That's wrong. You need to use,

```
$('div#update').load('home.php', function(data) {
  $('div#update').html(data).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Make sure your PHP file works properly by calling it directly and confirming that it returns the results properly.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: Thank-you John P, I have attempted Praveen's for now, however nothing I do will allow each div to update individually, it keeps loading the entire home.php into each div rather than just the #update information :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var $data = $('div#update');
$data.fadeOut('slow', function() { 
    $data.load('home.php div#update', function() { 
        $data.fadeIn('slow'); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference, it will be better to add an additional page in the same directory (eg: phpcode.php) and then put your php code also in there! then try this:

```
var $data = $('div#update');
$data.fadeOut('slow', function() { 
    $data.load('phpcode.php div#update', function() { 
        $data.fadeIn('slow'); 
    }); 
});
```